# how can a customize Dropzone form to work with css

Tags: html, css, dropzone.js

i have created a customized form with a textfield, dropzone upload area and a submit button as below. I am able to config the dropzone well like this https://www.dropzonejs.com/examples/simple.html.

However, i would like to beautify my dropzone into the the similar one in the try it out section in https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Can you please advise how can i do it? How can i amend the code into to meet into the structure of the dropzone so that i can use their css file? Thanks a lot for your great help.

```
<header>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/dropzone.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/basic.css')}}"/>
</header>

<body>
     <main>
        <section>
            <form action="{{url_for('main.handle_upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="post" name="post" required=""></textarea><br>
                <div class="dropzone" id="myDropzone"></div>
                <button type="submit" id="submit-all"> Submit and Upload </button>
            </form>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: "Can you please advise how can i do it?" CSS? You have HTML there, so write some CSS to target the elements and change them how you like. If you post your own attempt to style in a reproducible format, and point out where you are having trouble you will likely get some helpful suggestions here.

Comment: The dropzone module have the default css file which I can use if I follow standard format. I want to ask how can I still use the default css provided by dropzone if I have the above html (where the dropzone is kept under a div instead of a form. )Thanks.

Comment: Are you new to CSS? You can write your own custom style rules that apply to the drop zone in context of your page. By using selectors that are more specific than the library CSS you can override any style you want with your own.

Comment: Yes i am new to CSS so i ask question here. But my question is more in how to apply the default css of dropzone instead of customizing my own dropzone css. Thanks a lot for your time and info.